# Как сделать выполнение нескольких биндов одновременно

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на 2(или n) кнопки музыка проигрывалась одновременно?

```
...

def create_add_note(vert,img,mp3): 

    def add(event): 
        add_photo(vert,img) 
        plus()
        play_note(mp3)  
        Mylist.append(mp3) 

    return add
 ....

root.bind('a',create_add_note(140,DO,'1.mp3')) 

root.bind('s',create_add_note(130,RE,'2.mp3'))
```

Чтобы игралось сразу две(или больше) мелодий.

Comment: здесь три разных вопроса: **1-** *как выполнить две функции в Питоне параллельно* (здесь помогут подходы из ссылки, которую я вам уже давал [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://goo.gl/vg2zy9)) **2-** *как воспроизвести два mp3 файла одновременно* -- зависит от окружения и как файлы проигрываются (`mixer.Sound` поддерживает несколько файлов одновременно, pygame.mixer.music, [который вы возможно используете](https://goo.gl/cJJZiV)—[нет](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) **3-** [*как пианино реализовать*](https://goo.gl/hYga4d)

Comment: ... ([код по ссылке](https://goo.gl/UxnBKa) из [комментария](https://goo.gl/hYga4d) умеет больше одной ноты одновременно проигрывать). Какой из трёх вопросов вас сейчас больше интересует?